# How to trace the path of a moving point in geogebra

Tags: geometry, math-software

I created a simple animation in geogebra, two intersecting lines rotating around fixed points. I want to trace the paths of the vertex points of these lines.
I mean is there a way when the animation is running, I can trace the path(s) of points (E and C) or (B and F) or other such combinations or trace the paths of all circumferencial points.

How can I do that [image: A is fixed on (XY plane) and D is fixed on BC]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you want certain vertices to leave trails as they change their position. You can do it by right-clicking on the vertex and checking the "Trace On" option. Now the vertex will leave traces of it's colour on the canvas.

Comment: mbaitoff, really thank. This helps a lot